# Multicriteria increment with reset in R

Tags: r

I have a very large (nearly 6m rows) dataframe called DF with the following structure:

```
CodeContract    RelMonth    AmtPmt
A0001           10          0.00
A0001           11          15.00
A0002           12          4.55
A0003           4           0.00
...             ...         ...
```

`RelMonth` is defined as the number of months since a particular static event associated with the `CodeContract`.

This data is already sorted by `CodeContract` and by `RelMonth`. The data frame currently holds continuous `RelMonth`; i.e. for any given `CodeContract` all the interim `RelMonth`are populated such as that for a given `CodeContract` if I have Min `RelMonth=5` and Max `RelMonth=12`, then the data frame will include `RelMonths 5:12`.

I would like to calculate another column called `Mths_since_last_Pmt` which would count for a given `CodeContract`how many `RelMonths` it has been since a given a `CodeContract` had a `AmtPmt > Amt_threshold`.

It would work like this (assuming `Amt_threshold=5`)

```
CodeContract    RelMonth    AmtPmt  Mths_since_last_Pmt
A0001           1           0.00    1
A0001           2           3.00    2
A0001           3           0.00    3
A0001           4           10.00   0
A0001           5           0.00    1
A0002           1           10.00   0
A0002           2           12.00   0
A0002           3           0.00    1
A0002           4           0.00    2
```

I currently have a working solution that uses a `For` loop but it can only process around 5,000 rows/sec.

I am looking for a way to vectorize this calculation and maybe even without sorting the data first, or having uninterrupted `RelMonths`.

All vectorized solutions that I have tried to develop, typically with `ddply` that call `seq_along`, end up maxing out my RAM (24GB). I am looking for a solution that will run in under 2GB of RAM usage. Maybe a solution in the form of a custom function?

Any idea how to make this work?

Update
@Roland

@Roland

I have found a slightly different dataset that will result in an erroneous output with the code below. The tweaked input is:

```
DF <- read.table(text="CodeContract    RelMonth    AmtPmt  Mths_since_last_Pmt
A0001           1           0.00    1
A0001           2           3.00    2
A0001           3           0.00    3
A0001           4           10.00   0
A0001           5           0.00    1
A0002           1           1.00   0
A0002           2           14.00   0
A0002           3           14.00    1
A0002           4           14.00    2",header=TRUE)
```

The corresponding output is:

```
CodeContract RelMonth AmtPmt Mths_since_last_Pmt Mths_since_last_Pmt2
1:        A0001        1      0                   1                    1
2:        A0001        2      3                   2                    2
3:        A0001        3      0                   3                    3
4:        A0001        4     10                   0                    0
5:        A0001        5      0                   1                    1
6:        A0002        1      1                   0                    1
7:        A0002        2     14                   0                    0
8:        A0002        3     14                   1                   -1
9:        A0002        4     14                   2                   -2
```

The negative numbers `-1` and `-2` in `Mths_since_last_Pmt2` in the last rows are incorrect; they should both be `0` as the threshold has been exceed. It seems that the algorithm fails when the first item is the sub-group (here by `CodeContract` change) is below the threshold is enough to throw it off.

Is there a tweak that we can apply to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to find someone with a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581451/reset-cumsum-value-to-zero-in-r) on SO and was able to adapt the answer to my problem. Kudos to @sven-hohenstein

The answer goes like this:

```
require(data.table)
DF<-as.data.table(DF)
```

First, I created a threshold test vector, which returns `1` if the `AmtPmt` is below the threshold:

```
DF$trsh_test[DF$AmtPmt<trsh]<-1
DF$trsh_test[is.na(DF$trsh_test)]<-0
```

Second, with the `ave` function together with `seq_along`

```
DF[,Mths_since_last_Pmt2 := 
        trsh_test * ave(trsh_test, c(0L, cumsum(diff(trsh_test) != 0)), 
        FUN = seq_along) ,
        by=CodeContract]
```

You get the following output, which is correct:

```
CodeContract RelMonth AmtPmt Mths_since_last_Pmt trsh_test Mths_since_last_Pmt2
A0001        1      0                   1         1                    1
A0001        2      3                   2         1                    2
A0001        3      0                   3         1                    3
A0001        4     10                   0         0                    0
A0001        5      0                   1         1                    1
A0002        1      1                   0         1                    1
A0002        2     14                   0         0                    0
A0002        3     14                   1         0                    0
A0002        4     14                   2         0                    0
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="CodeContract    RelMonth    AmtPmt  Mths_since_last_Pmt
A0001           1           0.00    1
A0001           2           3.00    2
A0001           3           0.00    3
A0001           4           10.00   0
A0001           5           0.00    1
A0002           1           10.00   0
A0002           2           12.00   0
A0002           3           0.00    1
A0002           4           0.00    2",header=TRUE)

library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(DF,key=c("CodeContract","RelMonth"))

trsh <- 5
DT[,Mths_since_last_Pmt2 := 
       cumsum(AmtPmt<=trsh)-cumsum(cumsum(AmtPmt<=trsh)*(AmtPmt>trsh)),
            by=CodeContract]

#    CodeContract RelMonth AmtPmt Mths_since_last_Pmt Mths_since_last_Pmt2
# 1:        A0001        1      0                   1                    1
# 2:        A0001        2      3                   2                    2
# 3:        A0001        3      0                   3                    3
# 4:        A0001        4     10                   0                    0
# 5:        A0001        5      0                   1                    1
# 6:        A0002        1     10                   0                    0
# 7:        A0002        2     12                   0                    0
# 8:        A0002        3      0                   1                    1
# 9:        A0002        4      0                   2                    2
```

Hopefully data.table's assignment by reference will keep you under the RAM limit.

Comment: Hi Roland, it seems that this algorithm doesn't always work. Mths_since_last_Pmt2 sometimes gets negative values, seemingly when there are multiple payments above the threshold.

Can you check that there isn't a mistake in the entry you posted?