# Reset cumsum value to zero in R

Tags: r

I have a problem. For example I have  this :

```
id  truth count
1   1     1
2   1     2
3   0     0
4   1     1
5   1     2
6   1     3
8   0     0
```

**I tried this:**

```
fun <- rle(df$truth)

df$count <- unlist(sapply(fun$lengths, function(x) {return(1:x)}))
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if two or more consecutive zeros occur in `truth`? How does your code fail?

Comment: If more consecutive zeros occur then count equals always zero except when is in the column "Truth" 1. And then repeat 1,2,3. For example:1 0 0 0 1 1 1 -> 1 0 0 0 1 2 3

Comment: Why not just add at the end: `df$count[df$truth == 0] <- 0`?

Comment: @MarkMiller , where at the end, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach. Based on `ave`:

```
transform(dat, count = truth * ave(truth, c(0L, cumsum(diff(truth) != 0)), 
                                   FUN = seq_along))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: No it is not working :-/ the result is: 1 1 0 3 1 1 0

Comment: I have a little question : can i do it without ave and with only ifelse (or if and else) conditions?

Comment: @user3275732 You could do it with a loop and `if` and `else`, but it would be less efficient. What's the problem with using `ave`?

Comment: No no it is working. But I am courious. I found a few days ago one code with if conditions but its so long :)